# F# profiling tools in Visual Studio 11

Tags: visual-studio, f#, visual-studio-2012

As a student I have access to VS2010 Pro only which does not provide good profiling tools so you can tune performance of your F# (or other) multithreaded programs. It would seem that Visual Studio 11 Pro Beta has the Concurrency Visualizer and other Analysis tools.

Could anyone confirm if these are the same tools that are available in VS2010 Premium/Ultimate? An overview of the available tools in VS11 and their use would be useful.

**EDIT**
From the MSDN VS2010 documentation ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx)), it is clear that the Profiling Tools are restricted to VS Premium and Ultimate only.

For VS11 Beta, the documentation ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) does not (yet) say in which editions the tools will be available. Concurrency Visualizer has many new additions and hopefully it stays in the Pro edition.

This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives a good overview of the new stuff in VS11 Beta, including profiling and analysis tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no profiling tools in VS2010 Pro.  However there are many profilers  you can use.  In particular Mono has a good [profiler](http://www.mono-project.com/Profiler).  The Eqatec [profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/Home.aspx) is also quite good.

Comment: the Eqatec profiler is not 100% free. but i will give monodevelop and the profiler a try. so far i found the profiling tools in VS the best for f# performance analysis.